# How to implement bubble sort to sort string length from largest to smallest?

Tags: javascript, bubble-sort

How to implement bubble sort to sort string length from largest to smallest?

I tried this but it is sorted from smallest to largest

```
function order(array) {

  for ( let i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++ ) {
    for ( let j = i ; j < array.length ; j++ ) {

      if ( array[i].length < array[j].length ) {
        let temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
      }

    }
  }

  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well... if this comparison

```
if ( array[i].length < array[j].length ) {
  /* swap */
}
```

sorts in ascending order...

What comparison might sort in descending order?

Comment: I switched but it still doesn't work